# jQuery $.post deferred

Tags: jquery

How do I use a deferred with jQuery's `$.post`? I tried:

```
var myFunc = function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log(data);
};
var post = $.post("/url/", someData);
$.when(post).done(myFunc);
```

The usual

```
$.post("/url/", someData, function(data) { myFunc(data) });
```

works fine (after changing the `myFunc` signature).

`$.when...` doesn't work, and no errors show me failures. What exactly is the `.done()` function passing into `myFunc`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The jQuery ajax functions return a [jqXHR](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR) which is itself a deferred object (it implements the Promise interface). So no need for `$.when()`.

There is also no need to use a named function expression for `myFunc`, a normal function declaration is fine.

```
function func1(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    console.log('success', data);
}

function func2(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    console.log('done', textStatus);
}

$.post('/url/', someData).success(func1).done(func2);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/ng7zT/

---

> What exactly is the `.done()` function passing into `myFunc`?

This is documented at the jqXHR link above, and also at [`$.post`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post).

> The success callback function is passed the returned data, which will be an XML root element or a text string depending on the MIME type of the response. It is also passed the text status of the response.
>
> As of jQuery 1.5, the success callback function is also passed a "jqXHR" object (in jQuery 1.4, it was passed the XMLHttpRequest object).

Comment: There is no need for [$.when](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/), but it should not hurt, either.