# Variable not working as expected JQuery

Tags: jquery, variables, post

I have a function:

```
function name(type)
{
    $.i="";
    $.post("name.php", type, function(data, status){
        $(".pic").attr("src", data);
        $.i=data;

    })
    alert($.i); //this is not working
}
```

In the above code the alert is displaying empty alert box. But when i have

```
function name(type)
{
    $.i="";
    $.post("name.php", type, function(data, status){
        $(".pic").attr("src", data);
        $.i=data;
        alert($.i); //now this is working
    })

}
```

I want to return the value returned by name.php file . `name.php` contains `echo "string"`.
It is for testing only. In the second given code `string` is displaying but in first it is not working.

What can i do to return the value from the function and assign the received value to variable declared outside $.post() or in the function.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The async call back of post is call after the execution of post. You can call a function from post to perform operation on value return in callback.

```
function name(type)
{
    $.i="";
    $.post("name.php", type, function(data, status){
        $(".pic").attr("src", data);
        $.i=data;
        //alert($.i); //now this is working
        callToFunctionPassingData(data);
    })    
}
```

You can try using deffered execution this [**post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433696/jquery-post-deferred) will guid you how to achieve it.

Comment: i need to return value from function. I had created a function and in that function gave `return data` but in calling side `alert(name("t"))` is showimg `undefined`

Comment: how can i return the value to where name() is calling

Comment: Did you read the post, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433696/jquery-post-deferred