# Callback when AJAX calls are done using jQuery when

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, shopify, .when

I am having trouble making the callback work correctly. Here is what I am trying to achieve: I have 2 items that I want to add to cart so I make 2 asynchronous POST requests. Once those two POST requests are complete, then I want to update the partial view of the cart. The issue is that it seems like only 1 item gets added to cart. When I debug it, then 2 of the items gets added. Any suggestion or help would be great. Thanks in advance!

here is my code:

```js
var cart = []

function AddToCart(input) {
  return $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add.js',
    data: input,
    dataType: 'json'
  })
  .done(function(data) {
    return data;
  });
}  

$("#addToCart").click(function() {
  $('#capsContainer input:checked').each(function() {
    var cartItem = {
      id: $(this).val(),
      quantity: 1
    }

    cart.push(cartItem);
  });

  var test1 = AddToCart(cart[0]);
  var test2 = AddToCart(cart[1]);

  $.when.apply(test1, test2).done(function() {
        $.getJSON('/cart.js', function(data) {
        $('.cart-item-count').text(data.item_count);
        $('.cart-item-price').html(formatMoney(data.total_price));      
        ShowCart();
    });
  })
});
```

Comment: `$.ajax` returns a `jqXHR` object which is already deferred, so using `$.when` is not advised here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery $.post deferred](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6433696/jquery-post-deferred)

Comment: @SterlingArcher I did that before using $.when where the callback in $.when was in the done() but it seems to only processed one of the POST request. How do you make it wait until both the POST requests are completed?

Comment: You might consider using the library named _ajaxq.js_  which can be used to queue up ajax requests in groups, which you can then embed requests into the callback part of a $.postq()  request which follows the same syntax as $.post()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of  the issue is that your using ajax requests which could occur either before or after the code happens to handle those executions. Since they are async, its possible that they could fire/return before  any other code runs on the page depending on how your browser's Javascript parser decides to execute the code. Rather than attempting to use Callbacks on asynchronous ajax requests,  you can control the entire interaction by using a small 600 byte library called **ajaxq.js**

**ajaxq.js** essentially works just like jQuery's  `$.post()`  method, only you can also specify multiple queues by name to execute asyncronously, and attach a callback to them or whatever.

Here's a quick example of how you could setup your Ajax Cart Preview using this library.

```
/* queue up an AJAX request */
$.postq("set_data", "add_items.php", {"itemID": someItemID, "customerID": customerID },
  function(result1) {


  /* perform new request at the end of first request */

  $.postq("get_data", "get_items.php", { "id": customerID }, 
      function(result2) {

    /* add in code to perform at the end of the second ajax POST request */

  }); // end of request 2

}); // end of request 1
```

---

Here's your example using the **ajaxq.js** library:

```
function AddToCart(input) {
   $.postq("add_item", "/cart/add/js", input, function(result) {
        preview_items();
    }, "json");

}  

function preview_items() {
 $.getJSON('/cart.js', function(data) {
        $('.cart-item-count').text(data.item_count);
        $('.cart-item-price').html(formatMoney(data.total_price));      
        ShowCart();
}


$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("#addToCart").on("click" function() {
    $('#capsContainer input:checked').each(function(elem) {
      var cartItem = {
        id: $(this).val(),
       quantity: 1
      }

      cart.push(cartItem);
    });

    var test1 = AddToCart(cart[0]);
    var test2 = AddToCart(cart[1]);

  });
```

Comment: I think I literally said the exact same thing when I found it -- seems to be the solution to many problems related to ajax and its asynchronous ways

Answer (score 0):

Your AddToCart method already returns a deferred object. You are calling .done method twice.

I guess your code should look like this.

```
var cart = []

function AddToCart(input) {
  return $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/cart/add.js',
    data: input,
    dataType: 'json'
  });
}  

$("#addToCart").click(function() {
  $('#capsContainer input:checked').each(function() {
    var cartItem = {
      id: $(this).val(),
      quantity: 1
    }

    cart.push(cartItem);
  });

  var test1 = AddToCart(cart[0]);
  var test2 = AddToCart(cart[1]);

  $.when(test1, test2).done(function() {
        $.getJSON('/cart.js', function(data) {
            $('.cart-item-count').text(data.item_count);
            $('.cart-item-price').html(formatMoney(data.total_price));      
            ShowCart();
        });
      })
});
```

Comment: I tried this but it still adds one item each time I click the Add to Cart button. The only time it adds both the items is when I debug it. So weird